# Cleveref Appendices Environment. And default formatting

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, appendices, cleveref

I have some questions regarding `cleveref` and the `appendix` Package. 
I've read the documentation but can't seem to find a solution.

So I have this document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,,numbers=enddot,listof=totoc,
   toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Formatting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Europäische fontcodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsch
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[page,titletoc,title,toc]{appendix}

%PDF Options (Change Before Print)
\usepackage[
    pagebackref=false,
    plainpages=false, % zur korrekten Erstellung der Bookmarks
    pdfpagelabels, % zur korrekten Erstellung der Bookmarks
    %hypertexnames=false, % zur korrekten Erstellung der Bookmarks
]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}


\usepackage[ngerman,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

    \section{TestSection}
    Test: \cref{app:1}

    \vspace{5cm}

    \begin{appendices}
        \section{Erster Anhang}\label{app:1}
        \blindtext
    \end{appendices}

    \vspace{5cm}
    \section{Continue Numbering}

\end{document}
```

The Output then looks like this:

[image: Latex Output]

And now for my questions:

1. Why does the `\Cref` still say "Abschnitt" (German for "section") and not "Anhang" (German for "Appendix"). I have tested it with `\appendix` but that breaks the numbering of the section after the `appendices` environment.
2. The appendix Package is loaded with the option `title`. Why is the Title still in English while everything else translates?

Comment: You are asking too much questions in one, sorry. The `TOC` question from your edit is totally unrelated to your `cleveref`  issue

Comment: I've taken the liberty of deleting the third question along with the supplemental question. This site really works best when a posting contains just one major query -- or two closely-related queries. Feel free to post additional, new queries in which you raise additional questions about `cleveref` or cross-referencing methods in general.

Answer (score 4):

The names of the `appendix` ToC and page entries must be changed with `\addto\captionsngerman{...}` to take effect.

The `cleveref` package must be informed that a `\section` in the `appendices` environment should be referenced as `Anhang` (appendix). The instruction `\label[app]{app:1}` uses an optional argument for `\label` to indicate the cross-reference type, this optional argument is an invention of `cleveref`.  (See the comment by Mico below.)

I don't address the other issues since there are too many questions in one post. I am also not sure whether a KOMA class and the `appendix` package  should be loaded together at all (most likely, they will interfere in the very end)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,numbers=enddot,listof=totoc,
    toc=sectionentrywithdots,ngerman]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Formatting
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Europäische fontcodierung
\usepackage{babel} % Deutsch
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[page,titletoc,title,toc]{appendix}


\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\sffamily Anhänge}
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anhänge}
}


%PDF Options (Change Before Print)
\usepackage[
   pagebackref=false,
   plainpages=false, % zur korrekten Erstellung der Bookmarks
   pdfpagelabels, % zur korrekten Erstellung der Bookmarks
   % hypertexnames=false, % zur korrekten Erstellung der Bookmarks
]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\usepackage[ngerman,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}   
\crefname{app}{Anhang}{Anhänge}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{TestSection}
Test: \cref{app:1}


\clearpage
\begin{appendices}
   %%\crefformat{section}{#2\appendixname\ #1#3}
   \section{Erster Anhang}\label[app]{app:1}
   \blindtext
\end{appendices}

\section{Continue Numbering}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I vote your excellent work. +1

Comment: +1. I think (but am not entirely sure about this...) that the OP would like the cross-referencing call-out to the appendix section to be formatted as `Anhang A` rather than as `Abschnitt A`. If that's the case, the easiest solution is probably to (a) change the `\label` instruction from `\label{app:1}` to `\label[app]{app:1}`and (b) provide the instruction `\crefname{app}{Anhang}{Anhänge}` in the preamble (after loading `cleveref`, of course). You could then ditch the command `\Crefformat{section}{#2\appendixname #1#3}` after `\begin{appendices}`.

Comment: @Mico: Isn't the OP not complaining/asking why the `\cref` still says `Abschnitt` where he assumes it to be `Anhang`?

Comment: @Mico: Let me check...

Comment: @Mico: You're right, I thought I had attacked that issue as well. Well, I know of course of `\label[...]{...}` and will incorporate that in the solution to make it 'complete', but still looking for another way. Thanks!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of applying a few, minor edits to your answer. Feel free to revert. I've also edited the original query to delete the third and fourth questions, as they didn't have much of a connection to the main (and reasonably well-articulated) questions.

Comment: @Mico: I saw your 'minor' edits ... and 'improved' them (:-P) Thanks